# I want to use redux saga instead of redux thunk. Will this cause any problems in future in my application?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, redux-thunk

I'm usually used to React Saga so I want to use Redux Tool Kit and Saga. Butt is confused about whether this will be a problem later.

Comment: It's definitely more complex and not the "default" choice, but it may be justified if your app deals with really complex async flows. You can really only answer this yourself. I personally found thunk to be sufficient for any requirements I have encountered, but people's experience differs of course.

Comment: Outside of more complex async flows, saga also excels at separations of concerns if you want to have more robust architecture - but that again starts to make sense only at certain scale.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem if you configure it correctly, I have used it in more than 3 large projects with the complex flow but didn't have a problem in the saga

Answer (score 1):

Redux-saga works perfectly fine with Redux Toolkit.

Keep in mind though that Redux Saga is only useful in very complicated scenarios and almost no apps are complicated enough to really warrant it's use. That's why the official Redux Style guide recommends to [use Thunks for async logic](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#use-thunks-for-async-logic) until you come to a point where it is not sufficient any more.

You can also easily combine thunks and saga in the same app, using the more simple thunks per default and only using sagas where you really need them, keeping the mental load down.